# Putting unittest classes in the related script itself vs making a separate file

Tags: python, unit-testing

So I'm creating unit tests for all of my scripts, many of which arent oo, and have main-loop code. I was wondering what the standard is for the location of creating unittest classes in relation to the affected script. Should the unit test be in a separate file which imports the script, and then function-alize the mainloop code? Or can it shoved at the end of the the related script?

Comment: What do you mean by not OO?  I don't think that's relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate your tests into a file of their own, and extract functions from your main so that they can be tested.

(After you've extracted the functions, you might notice that a lot of data is being shared between them, hinting that you should be creating a class.)

You'll have a file like this:

```
def func_1():
    ...

def func_2():
    ...

def main():
    ....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And a file separate test file that tests those `func_*` functions.

Also, like @eli-bendersky says, those `func_*` functions should be extracted into their own module if they are all related enough, so they can easily be reused by other scripts, but this is a start.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to have some related functionality bundled in a module. For that module, you create a separate file with unittests. The convention is to name it `test_foo.py` if your module is `foo.py`.

Where it sits exactly is not well defined, although a separate directory named `test` or something similar is common.

And that has nothing to do with the nature of your code. It can be classes or functions, whatever, as long as it's testable. Of course, making it amenable to testing is not always trivial.

Answer (score 0):

One additional reason for not putting the unit tests in source file is that during distribution/packaging of your python application you can exclude all the directories that contains the tests.